# Layout with AETemplates in Maya

Tags: templates, attributes, maya

In a maya AE<class>template.mel file I define a layout for 2 checkboxes and other fields:

```
editorTemplate -beginLayout "MyLayout" -collapse 1;
    editorTemplate -addControl "dynamic"; <- CHECKBOX 1
    editorTemplate -addControl "useEmitterSpeed"; <- CHECKBOX 2
    editorTemplate -addControl "Initial_speed";
    editorTemplate -addControl "relative";
editorTemplate -endLayout;
```

But they appear on the same line:
[image]
How can I have the 2nd checkbox below the first one and not on its right ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `editorTemplate -beginNoOptimize` and `editorTemplate -endNoOptimize`. E.g.

```
editorTemplate -beginLayout "MyLayout" -collapse 1;
    editorTemplate -beginNoOptimize;
    editorTemplate -addControl "dynamic"; // CHECKBOX 1
    editorTemplate -addControl "useEmitterSpeed"; // CHECKBOX 2
    editorTemplate -endNoOptimize;
    editorTemplate -addControl "Initial_speed";
    editorTemplate -addControl "relative";
editorTemplate -endLayout;
```

More info here: [Maya Help](https://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2017/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/CommandsPython/editorTemplate.html#flagbeginNoOptimize)

Answer (score 0):

Normally when creating a ui in Maya you use

setParent '..'

Put it under the first checkbox

Maya stores the last creates ui element and tries to parent it under as a convenience instead of having to tell each object where it belongs every time

Not sure if it works for the AE